# How should posted data be modeled in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, design-patterns, viewmodel

I think I get the idea of the `ViewModel` in `MVC` but, when doing updates and deletes, it seems like there should be a distinct model for posting to the controller. I noticed the default razor controllers use `ViewBag` to hold Selectlists.

I guess that makes the `ViewModel` (domain entities really) reusable on the return trip because it is stripped of unnecessary data. But it seems like resorting to `ViewBag` doesn't make sense when using view models because the view model can contain the `Selectlist`s and such.

**So my question** is what kinds of patterns are there for making distinct "posted data" models? (got this term from Esposito's MVC 2 book) And how should the posted data model be related to the view models? For example, it seems like I will try including the posted data models with the view models. I'm new to `MVC` and not coming from a `web-forms` background either. I would really like to understand the best patterns for modeling the data that will be sent to the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often I use the same view model for passing it to the Edit/Update view and receiving it in the POST action. Here's the commonly used pattern:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    DomainModel model = ... fetch the domain model given the id
    ViewModel vm = ... map the domain model to a view model
    return View(vm);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ViewModel vm)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // there were validation errors => redisplay the view
        // if you are using dropdownlists because only the selected
        // value is sent in the POST request you might need to 
        // repopulate the property of your view model which contains
        // the select list items
        return View(vm);
    }

    DomainModel model = ... map the view model back to a domain model
    // TODO: process the domain model

    return RedirectToAction("Success")
}
```

As far as the mapping between the domain model and view models is concerned I would recommend you [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/).

Comment: why do we need to map the `ViewModel` to `DomainModel`?why do we not pass the `DomainModel` to our action instead of `ViewModel`?

Comment: @Miroprocessor, because you have passed the view model to this view initially. So this view contains only the input fields for this view model. Controller actions should take/pass only view models to and from views. If you have your controller action take DomainModel as argument most of the properties of this domain model will null because they were not POSTed and the model binder wouldn't know how to resolve them.

Comment: @Darin, Thank you for your quick reply. It does seems like the pattern you showed is the one I've heard about the most so far. Still it seems like it would really simplify the controllers if I created a ControllerModel that could be included in the view models. Then I would have modeled the M, the V, and the C huh? Is this a bad idea or have you tried anything like it? Thanks again.

Comment: @Benjamin, unless your controller has a single action to handle a single view that would be a bad design. You should have a view model per view. Not per controller.

Comment: Maybe I should have said ActionModel - not ControllerModel - to be more specific.

Comment: @Benjamin, you can call it as you like as long as it is tied to a given view. Personally I use the ViewModel suffix naming convention but you could use any name that you feel comfortable with.

Comment: @Darin, I don't know, I figured I might break something. :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Benjamin, no it wouldn't break anything. It's just a name of a class :-)